# On firing action in redux, it says action isn't defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am newbie to redux and making a todo list in the redux. My action creator code looks like :

```
    /**
 * This file is called Action Creator (creates actions)
 *
 * Actions are objects as :
 * {
 *    type : 'ADD_TODO'     //the only thing needed is type
 *    text: 'this is our first to do'
 * }
 */

module.exports = {

  addTodo: function (text) {
    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({type: 'ADD_TODO', data: text});
    };
  }

};

//export default actions = {
//  addTodo(text) {
//    return {
//      type: 'ADD_TODO',
//      text: text
//    }
//  }
//};
//
```

Instead of returning object from the action, I am returning a function. So in the store.js file, I've used `thunkMiddleware` from `react-redux`.

My store.js code looks like :

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from '../reducers/reducers';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

//We separated out the store from the client.js file so that if we have to add middleware here and change our state, we can do that here
//Add middlewares on actions here

let finalCreateStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState = {todos: []}) {
  return finalCreateStore(reducer, initialState);
}
```

but while firing an action, it says that  **action is not defined**

**[Edit]**

My Reducer looks like this:

```
function getId(state) {
  return state.todos.reduce((maxId, todo) => {
      return Math.max(todo.id, maxId)
    }, -1) + 1;
}

export default function reducer(state, actions) {
  switch (actions.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      Object.assign({}, state, {
        todos: [{
          //add new to do
          text: action.text,
          completed: false,
          id: getId(state)
        }, ...state.todos]
      });
      break;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Also I'm firing actions using `connect` as :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return state;
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    addTodo: (todo) => {
      dispatch(addTodo(todo));
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

I don't have any clue how can I get rid of this error.

Comment: how you firing the action ?

Comment: what does your reducer look like?

Comment: @abhirathore2006 edited the question details

Comment: @azium edited the question details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reducer signature is `(state, actions)` but in the function body you have `action`. You probably meant:

```
function reducer (state, action) {
   // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your reducer. You define `actions` as second parameter, but on one line (I added a comment there) you try to read from `action`, which is not defined.

```
export default function reducer(state, actions) {
    switch (actions.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            Object.assign({}, state, {
                todos: [{
                    //add new to do
                    text: action.text, // <- action is not defined, but actions is
                    completed: false,
                    id: getId(state)
                }, ...state.todos]
            });
            break;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

It's probably nice to call it `action` instead of `actions`, because it's just a single action.